# How to use Objects in Python effectively

Tags: python, oop

So I am trying to create a virtual book store and when I run my code I keep getting an error.

```
ask = True
def stop():
while ask:
    stop_or_no()

def stop_or_no():
menu = int(input(" 1: Display Books \n 2: Add to cart: \n 3 Show cart  \n 4: Checkout \n 5: Quit \nSelect an option in number form: "))


class Book:
    def __init__(self,title,author,genre,price):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.genre = genre
        self.price = price
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + "," + self.author + "," + self.genre + "," + str(float(self.price))
if menu == 1:

    book1 = Book("A visual Encyclopedia","Chris Woodford", "Science", 23.99)
    book2 = Book("My First Human Body Book", "Patricia J. Wynne and Donald M. Silver","Science", 3.99)
    book3 = Book("The Runaway Children", "Sandy Taylor","Fiction", 3.99)
    book4 = Book("The Tuscan Child", "Rhys Bowen","Fiction", 9.99)
    book5 = Book("Learning Python", "Mark Lutz","Programming", 61.99)
class Inventory:
    books = {1000 : str(book1), 1001 : str(book2), 1002 : str(book3), 1003 : str(book4), 1004 : str(book5)}
    print(books)

    def add_book1(self):
        book_list = open("C:\\Users\\brian\\Documents\\Coding\\booklist.txt")
        print(book_list.read())
    def display(self):
        print(books)
class Cart(Inventory):
    cart = []
    def add_book(self):
        total_price = 0
        to_buy_books = int(input("What is the item number you would like to buy?"))
        how_many_books = input("How many of that item would you like to buy?") 
        if to_buy_books == 1000:
            total_price += how_many_books * 23.99
            cart.append(to_buy_books)
        elif to_buy_books == 1001:
            total_price += how_many_books * 3.99
        elif to_buy_books == 1002:
            total_price += how_many_books * 3.99
            cart.append(to_buy_books)
        elif to_buy_books == 1003:
            total_price += how_many_books * 9.99
            cart.append(to_buy_books)
        else:
            total_price += how_many_books * 61.99
            cart.append(to_buy_books)



    def checkout(self):
        if total_price == 0:
            print("There is nothing in your cart")
        else:
            print(total_price)
            print("Thank you for shopping with us today! Please come back again!")

if menu == 2:
    cart1 = Cart.add_book
elif menu == 3:
    if len(cart) == 0:
        print("Cart is empty")
    else:
        print(str(cart))
elif menu == 4:
    Cart.checkout
else:
    ask = False
    print("Thank you for using this application")


stop()
```

I expected the code to run smoothly, but when I run it, it prints this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Coding\FinalProject_Bmason1270130.py", line 81, in <module>
    stop()
  File "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Coding\FinalProject_Bmason1270130.py", line 7, in stop
    stop_or_no()
  File "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Coding\FinalProject_Bmason1270130.py", line 28, in stop_or_no
    class Inventory:
  File "C:\Users\brian\Documents\Coding\FinalProject_Bmason1270130.py", line 29, in Inventory
    books = {1000 : str(book1), 1001 : str(book2), 1002 : str(book3), 1003 : str(book4), 1004 : str(book5)}
NameError: free variable 'book1' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

Comment: You have indentation and organizational issues in this post that make it difficult to guess what code you are actually running. Reproducing your error also requires knowing what inputs you provided to the program; one possibility that (1) is not your first choice, meaning you try to use `book1` before you've actually defined it (by selecting (1)).

Answer (score 0):

You define book1 if menu == 1, but if menu != 1, then book1 is undefined.
Next You define a class Inventory, which has a class variable, 
that uses book1, which if menu != 1 is undefined. 
Keep in mind that class variables get evaluated when class is defined,
as you can see in this example.

```py
class Obj:
    var = print('var init')
```

which immediately prints 'var init'.
Just define book1, …, book5 in any scope you will need them.